# Different versions of Hatcher

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I suddenly found out that my Hatcher from amazon is very different from the version on his website. Should I assume his website is up to date, and hence my copy is an old version?

Comment: it seems the version from his site is more up to date than print editions. For me, i like an actual book in my hands. It would appear that if you download sections and print out just pages that differ, for instance new exercises, you will be in good shape. Still, it has always been a good book.

Comment: Oh no, so I got an old version. Hope I can get a new one from the vendor... Thanks @WillJagy

Comment: I do not believe there is anything available other than reprints with minor corrections on the 2001/2002 edition. See http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/algebraic-topology-1

Comment: Yes, amazon also says it has December 2001. You have the most recent thing in an actual published book form. If you want to spend a surprising amount of money, print out the latest 550 page version from his web site and pay someone to bind it for you; but the usual bindings at photocopy shops will not make a convenient book at this size. Still, I have done exactly this at times. I get the binding that allows one to open it flat.

Comment: @WillJagy +1 for a "surprising amount of money". Sadly...

Comment: @Marie, I did a bit more, just once. In the late 1980's Celso Costa's new examples of complete minimal surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$ appeared. I met M. do Carmo at a conference. He sent me Costa's dissertation. I made two copies; I found a place that did actual library bindings, and had two copies made. I gave one to UC San Diego math library, one to UC Berkeley. It's still there, according to the web catalog: http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b13696950~S1

Comment: @WillJagy It's not that expensive. Use the free printing one gets as a grad student, take it to Copy Central on University and Shattuck, pay 3 dollars, and get it coil bound. Even better, in my opinion, than an actual book.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, I did not realize you were a student here. Been a while for me, of course.

Comment: @WillJagy Yep! Started this year. By "here", does that imply that you're at Berkeley right now?

Comment: @AlexYoucis, not at, I live in town. Got my Ph.D. in winter 1988. Math. Never got tenure and moved back. I'm in the phone book.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically no up to date versions in print form. The pdf of the book on his website is quite regularly updated. There is a cumulative list of corrections available on the website too. I printed my edition as a booklet of individual chapters (4 pages on each sheet of paper) and bound them myself into a book using a needle and some yarn. There are tutorials on book binding online, it is not that hard once you learned the basic and certainly way cheaper than buying the book or letting it print and bind professionally. If you don't want to take the time to bind it yourself, just fold it and staple it at the fold from the backside..